# How to tell the difference between free-tier Azure CosmosDB account and the paid one?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

When I create a new account using Azure portal, I can see "Apply Free Tier Discount" option. And this option is absent when there is an existing free-tier account in the current subscription.

But after the account is created I can't tell if it's free-tier or not. Can't find any difference between free-tier and not free-tier accounts either in the account properties in Azure portal either in ARM template auto-generated for the account. All templates have the same property "databaseAccountOfferType": "Standard". Somehow MS knows when one free-tier for a subscription already exists. So there is some indicator somewhere inside, but it's hidden from Azure portal users.

And another question: can I create a free-tier account using ARM template? If so, how can I be sure that I created a free-tier account if I use ARM template?

Comment: Mark Brown recently shared an ARM template for this on Twitter: https://gist.github.com/markjbrown/03d3640a2d915f5899b84e5927e4e589

Comment: I like when my twitter account is an answer on Stack.

Answer (score 4):

To find out if an account is created in free tier or not, you could fetch the properties of that account. I tried by executing REST API from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db-resource-provider/databaseaccounts/get.

Under `properties` node, you will see a property called `enableFreeTier`. That property's value will be `true` for free account and `false` for other accounts.

This is what I see when I run the REST API:

```
  "properties": {
    "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
    "documentEndpoint": "https://account.documents.azure.com:443/",
    "ipRangeFilter": "",
    "publicNetworkAccess": "Enabled",
    "enableAutomaticFailover": false,
    "enableMultipleWriteLocations": false,
    "enablePartitionKeyMonitor": false,
    "isVirtualNetworkFilterEnabled": false,
    "virtualNetworkRules": [],
    "EnabledApiTypes": "Sql",
    "disableKeyBasedMetadataWriteAccess": false,
    "enableFreeTier": true,//True is returned for free account, false otherwise
    "apiProperties": null,
    "databaseAccountOfferType": "Standard",
    "consistencyPolicy": {
      "defaultConsistencyLevel": "Session",
      "maxIntervalInSeconds": 5,
      "maxStalenessPrefix": 100
    },
```

For the sake of completeness, copying @juunas's comment about ARM template.

Here's the link to the ARM template that can be used to create a "free" account: https://gist.github.com/markjbrown/03d3640a2d915f5899b84e5927e4e589.

Comment: Thank you, @Gaurav! Using Azure Powershell (Get-AzResource) also works, I can see this property value in the returned object. At least this way I can control my resources.
But still a shame that portal users can't see it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it was not exposed on portal before, but currently this is also visible in Azure Portal on account overview blade under Essentials it is displayed as "Free Tier Discount" with value of either "Opted Out" or "Opted In".

Comment: it wasn't at least a year ago. But good to know it's finally available). I did not notice, so thanks for the tip)